# "PDO exception: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed" after changing DNS resolvers, with DB running on AWS

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, dns

In our Laravel 5.2 app, we have a DB setup running on AWS, using multiple read servers (and multiple DB connections).

At night, we changed the DNS resolvers for all web servers to the Google DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4). Then, the servers started spitting these:

> PDOException: Exception 'PDOException' with message '**SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service
>   not known**' in
>   /home/forge/studydrive.net/releases/20170320162143/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:55

The code at `Connector.php:55` is simply the PDO constructor:

```
public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
{
    $username = Arr::get($config, 'username');

    $password = Arr::get($config, 'password');

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options); // <== THIS ONE
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $pdo = $this->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection(
            $e, $dsn, $username, $password, $options
        );
    }

        return $pdo;
    }
```

The **.env** config for the AWS (with sesnsitive parts changed):

```
DB_HOST=myapp-cluster.cluster-123abc.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_HOST_WRITE=myapp-cluster.cluster-123abc.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_HOST_READ=myapp-cluster.cluster-ro-123abc.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

So, it seems like PHP's PDO suddenly cannot resolve the `DB_HOST` name.

Note, that we cannot use an IP for the `DB_HOST`, as the hostname (on the AWS side) maps to 3 different database READ servers.

Also, before we changed the resolvers, all was working fine.

**Anyone has any idea what might be causing the PDO error, or how to resolve it?**

Comment: The painfully obvious conclusion is that the DNS resolvers can't resolve those DNS addresses. The real question is why since (presumably) they resolve other addresses(?).

Comment: That's the question, indeed. I'm starting to think there could be a problem on AWS side.

Comment: Be absolutely certain that you're using a public endpoint and access control allows remote access to it (don't know what sort of security setting that would be in the case of DNS but there may be one there). Amazon has lots of hosts that only resolve internally.

Comment: We were getting the same thing without changing DNS. Seems that there is some DNS resolution issue at AWS. Restarting PHP processes would clear the DNS cache in PHP and fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Brady, that's exactly what we did - rebooted. And yep, there has to something wrong going on on AWS, we will be contacting them. I will update the post if I get any answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in libc, according to:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1674733

php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known ubuntu

Comment: Yep, I've been told there's a patch committed already, but it's still being tested to get an official patch status. Should be ready in the next 24h.

Answer (score 4):

As of March 20th, many Ubuntu users across the web were suddenly having DNS resolution issues pop up in their applications due to a bad update pushed out by Canonical (the maintainers of Ubuntu) which breaks DNS resolution after a few hours of uptime. Here's the bug report where the issue was reported and triaged:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1674532

This may have resulted in failures of your CMS to update/install plugins/install themes, failures to connect to external APIs, and/or error messages similar to the following:

Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname
Could not resolve host: downloads.wordpress.org
cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: example.com in....
Fortunately Canonical has since been able to resolve the issue, but affected systems must update to acquire the fix. To do that, you'll need DNS working, so if it's currently down please first reboot your Droplet. Once DNS resolution is working as normal, please run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then you can check your versions to ensure you've got the right ones. This can be done with:

```
# sudo dpkg -l | grep "GNU C Library" | awk '{print $3}'
```

If you're on Ubuntu 16.X, you should see output similar to the following:

```
# sudo dpkg -l | grep "GNU C Library" | awk '{print $3}'
2.23-0ubuntu7
2.23-0ubuntu7
2.23-0ubuntu7
```

If you're on Ubuntu 14.X, you should see output similar to the following:

```
# sudo dpkg -l | grep "GNU C Library" | awk '{print $3}'
2.19-0ubuntu6.11
2.19-0ubuntu6.11
```

If you see older versions of those packages, you'll need to upgrade per the previous instructions to avoid this issue.

Comment: We're running 2.19-0ubuntu6.14 and are still having this problem...did it come back?

Comment: I'm having issues now too. Just upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and from apache to nginx. Not sure what the cause is, but this is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem after rebuilding my instance and I tried to restore a database snapshot. And ***restarting the App Servers*** solved the issue for me. Worked like a charm! :)