# Sporadic PDOException [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, docker, pdo, dns

So I keep sporadically getting the following error:

```
Type: PDOException
Code: 2002
Message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
File: /var/www/html/system/db.php
Line: 71
```

It started randomly after no particular event. I haven't changed anything relating to the database connection etc. I will make some requests, and it will be working fine, then will get this for a few seconds / minutes, then it will go back to working again.

```
$this->connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_SERVER.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

My host is similar to the following. Its a subdomain from my ISP, which shouldnt make any difference.

```
define("DB_SERVER", "name.plus.com:3306");
```

The machine is self hosted, so no AWS as this similar question here - ["PDO exception: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed" after changing DNS resolvers, with DB running on AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925765/pdo-exception-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-after-changing-dns)

Its running on some docker containers. I have rebooted the actual machine too.

**Why would it just randomly be unable to resolve that domain at certain points, and then work fine?**

Comment: Sounds like there's an issue with the DNS lookups for the name.plus.com hostname, probably at your ISP. Have you tried to see if the issue is resolved if you connect to the IP address instead of the hostname?

Comment: you could add an extra, public, name server (google : 8.8.8.8) in your /etc/resolv.conf.  Granted that wont solve the issue, merely walk around it, but until your ISP figures this out, you can continue testing/whatever.

Comment: I have the same issue, randomly, and I do have Google DNS server 8.8.8.8 on my `resolv.conf`; and my `DB_SERVER`  is actually a domain that point to 127.0.0.1 in `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

6 years later this info is probably not relevant for you anymore, but I still want to leave my recent findings as an answer here.

I just had this exact problem with an up-to-date roundcube setup using docker compose. Every ~10th request would return 500 `getaddrinfo failed`.

After some debugging I switched from `roundcube/roundcubemail:1.6.5-fpm-alpine` to `roundcube/roundcubemail:1.6.5-fpm` and the issue was gone. I think there is a bug in PHP/PDO in combination with Alpine Linux which produces this behavior. Note that I was unable to reproduce the problem using `nslookup`.